# Why can't I change a data type?

Tags: sql, oracle

Example from SQL server website:
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ALTER COLUMN column_name new_data_type(size);

My database:
ALTER TABLE customers 
ALTER COLUMN salesRepEmployeeNumber INT(38);

Why can I not change the data type in this example? 
I get this error:

ALTER TABLE customers ALTER COLUMN salesRepEmployeeNumber INT(38)
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Comment: `INT(38)` is not an Oracle type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using not the right script, this one is the one you're looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
  MODIFY salesRepEmployeeNumber INT;
```

Here's some documentation:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax(`ALTER COLUMN`). actual sytax(`MODIFY COLUMN`) is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name new_data_type(size);
```

And as gordon pointed that the `int(38)` is not valid. You must specify `int`, which is `number(38)` implicitly.

Comment: I am dumb... Thank you sir!!

Comment: Welcome to SO!! And accept the answer once option is available so that this question is marked as resolved.